# Dependencies are not installable

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I'm trying to install splash 0.7.12 as instructed in [the wiki](https://github.com/paperManu/splash/wiki/Installation), but keep getting this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 splash-mapper : Depends: libgsl2 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libpython3.5 (>= 3.5.0~b1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'm running a fresh install of ubuntu 18.04 and it has python 3.6.7.

I'm I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What is `splash-mapper`? Where you got it?

Comment: It's an open source projection mapping software designed to build giant screens in the shape of domes and other topologies. https://github.com/paperManu/splash/wiki

Comment: Got it from the [release page](https://github.com/paperManu/splash/releases) of the project

Comment: The most correct way would be to ask software developer about support of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with binary deb-package via [issues page](https://github.com/paperManu/splash/issues).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binary package is not compatible with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, but you can always download and run FlatPak version as written in [README](https://github.com/paperManu/splash#packages):

```
sudo apt install flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
sudo flatpak install flathub org.freedesktop.Platform//1.6
sudo flatpak install splash.flatpak
```